# Get first value from consecutive rows PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, row

I am using PySpark and I want to get the first status order by Date but only if there consecutive status, because the status can be more than once, but not more than one in a row. Here is my example of what i have:

| status | created_when | GP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-10-10 | A1 |
| B | 2022-10-12 | A1 |
| B | 2022-10-13 | A1 |
| C | 2022-10-13 | A1 |
| C | 2022-10-14 | A1 |
| B | 2022-12-15 | A1 |
| C | 2022-12-16 | A1 |
| D | 2022-12-17 | A1 |
| A | 2022-12-18 | A1 |

This is what I need:

| status | created_when | GP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-10-10 | A1 |
| B | 2022-10-12 | A1 |
| C | 2022-10-13 | A1 |
| B | 2022-12-15 | A1 |
| C | 2022-12-16 | A1 |
| D | 2022-12-17 | A1 |
| A | 2022-12-18 | A1 |

I think something like but dont know how to implement either:

```
when(row[status] == row[status] + 1) then row[status]
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: How is your dataframe ordered, i.e. on which columns? For example, why are the last four rows ordered B-C-D-A if they have the same date 2022-12-15? I'm asking this because pyspark, when reading data, does not care row order if you do not specify it, and that particular order B-C-D-A may be random.

Comment: Thats doesn't matter, i change it to me more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the answer to the problem. I realize i have to add another column to do the *partitionBy*.

```
w  = Window.partitionBy('GP').orderBy("create_when")
df_1= df_0.withColumn("lag",F.lag("status").over(w))\
           .where((F.col("status") != F.col("lag")) | (F.col("lag").isNull()))
```

Comment: Columns `GP` and `create_when` are not mentioned in your question, I suggest you to edit it so that future users with your same issue can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function ordered by date - that's why the order of your dataframe matters - and compare whether in the following row you have the same status as before: you can do this with the [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html) function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.orderBy('date')

df = (df
 .withColumn('status_lag', F.lag('status').over(w))
 .filter((F.col('status_lag') != F.col('status')) | (F.col('status_lag').isNull()))
 .drop('status_lag')
)

+------+----------+
|status|      date|
+------+----------+
|     A|2022-10-10|
|     B|2022-10-12|
|     C|2022-10-13|
|     B|2022-12-15|
|     C|2022-12-16|
|     D|2022-12-17|
|     A|2022-12-18|
+------+----------+
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not working at all. I dont have what you show at your dataframe, I get exactly the same as input

Comment: Ok I get why: in your sample dataframe, you have two statuses (B, C) in date 2020-10-13. Which of this should come first, and why? Or why you said before that it does not matter?

Comment: I said that because only matters if 2 status are consecutive by date, thats why status order doesnt matter. It is like somethiung like this `when(row[status] == row[status] + 1) then row[status]`

Comment: So for example, if you have in date 2020-10-13 both status B and C, and in date 2020-10-14 you have B and C as well, what would your expected output be?